# How to change button background color and text color using setSate in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change button background color and text color by using setState in react.

This is App.js

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class App extends Component {
  changeColor = () => {
    this.setState({
      background: 'red'
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='text-center pt-5'>
        <button onClick= {this.changeColor} className='btn btn-danger'>Click here</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize your state and bind the function:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { background: 'blue', textColor: 'pink' };
  this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);
}
```

You need to access the color via the state and set it to the style attribute.

```js
<button style={{ backgroundColor: this.state.background, color: this.state.textColor }} onClick={this.changeColor} className='btn btn-danger'>Click here</button>
```

Also, update your `changeColor` method to handle the text color:

```js
changeColor = () => {
  this.setState({
    background: 'red',
    textColor: 'orange'
  });
}
```

Comment: How to change button text color to black when I click the button